# Add new Instance of SQLEXPRESS to SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, sql-server-express

I am using SQL server for my application and I need to use a SQLEXPRESS instance as per the requirement. However, the only current instance in my sql server is MSSQLSERVER. How Do I add a new Instance?
What Changes does an instance make to the server or databases?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to actually install SQLExpress on the machine. It is not the same as Sql Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say MSSQLSERVER, I'm guessing you're referring to the default instance of whatever SQL Server edition/version is installed on your machine. If you connect to that instance via SSMS, connect to the instance and run

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('Edition')
```

That should tell you what edition you're running. It could be express, standard, etc...

If that is not what you need then you need to install an Express edition. It is available as a free download from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/Products/sql-server-editions/sql-server-express.aspx